# How can I install Java 8 on Debian 12 (bookworm)?

Tags: debian, java, jdk, openjdk

Under Debian 11, we typically use OpenJDK from adoptopenjdk.net.

This organization will no longer provide new releases: https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/ui/native/deb/dists/

Is there  a way to install Java 8 *JDK* (not the runtime) on a Debian 12?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using the distrubution offered by adoptium, called `temurin-8-jdk`

```
mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings

wget -O - https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.asc

echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.asc] https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb $(awk -F= '/^VERSION_CODENAME/{print$2}' /etc/os-release) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list

apt update 

apt install temurin-8-jdk
```

Optional to switch from an old repository

```
update-alternatives --config java # choose new java
update-alternatives --config javac # choose new javac
```

Answer (score 8):

Thorsten Glaser provides [a repository](http://www.mirbsd.org/%7Etg/Debs/debidx.htm) which includes OpenJDK 8, built using [the Debian OpenJDK 8 package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openjdk-8) (see also [Debian bug #989736](https://bugs.debian.org/989736)).

To install it on Debian 12, download the appropriate repository configuration file:

```bash
wget http://www.mirbsd.org/~tg/Debs/sources.txt/wtf-bookworm.sources
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo mv wtf-bookworm.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo apt update
```

You’ll then see `openjdk-8-jdk` etc. available for installation as usual:

```bash
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: This source does not offer openjdk any more

Comment: @sipiatti that’s temporary, it will be restored once the t64 migration in unstable settles down (see the linked bug for details).